# Virtualbox on a MacBook Pro causes black screen on resolutions bigger than 1920 x 1080

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed Virtualbox and have Ubuntu up in it. I use a Macbook pro and I installed guest extension on my Ubuntu.

My Display has a resolution of 2560x1280 Pixels but as soon as I scale the Virtualbox screen bigger than FullHD the ubuntu shows a black screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to configure grub to use 2560x1280 pixels?

Comment: After searching for some while and trying to do so I found out that I didn´t give the virtual machine enough video memory in the display settings. After increasing it to 128 MB Ubuntu was able to support the full display size.